# How to override a link tag with another in css

Tags: html, css, overriding

I have a page where I use 2 css styles:

```
<link type="text/css" href="base_form.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="extended_form.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And `extended_form.css` must come after the base.

Is there any way to force `extended_form.css` to override `base_form.css`?

Comment: Wait, why do you want to do this? Changing the order of the `<link>` tags is obviously the best way to do this, and would solve the issue. Other methods to get around this are not easily scalable, and require a lot of work to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried appending `!important` behind your current CSS-statements? It acts as an override and overrides the given style for the specified selector.

Example:

```
<!-- html -->
<html><body id="foo"></body></html>

<!-- css -->
body { background: #0000FF; }
body#foo { background: #FF0000; }
```

Usually assigning an id and using it as a selector overrides the "global" style applied to an element, however, consider the following css instead:

```
body { background: #0000FF !important; }
body#foo { background: #FF0000; }
```

The above statement would render `#foo` with the background set to `#0000FF` instead of `#FF0000`.

Check it out on jsFiddle.net:

http://jsfiddle.net/9sJqx/ "regular" prority

http://jsfiddle.net/WfNUX/ `!important` applied

Answer (score 1):

`!important` is the best way to override the style.

For ex:

`base_form.css` has style

```
.header {
  width:100%;
}
```

`extended_form.css` has style

```
.header {
  width:80%;
}
```

if you want to override the style in `extended_form.css`

```
.header {
  width:80% !important;
}
```